# Convert JSON Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Below is a JSON array:

```
{
  "element": [
    {
      "name": "Donald",
      "gender": "M",
      "country": "US",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Hilary",
      "gender": "F",
      "country": "FR",
      "id": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Obama",
      "gender": "M",
      "country": "JP",
      "id": "3"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to format it as seen in the snippet below:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Donald",
    "gender": "M",
    "country": "US",
    "id": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Hilary",
    "gender": "F",
    "country": "FR",
    "id": "2"
  },
  {
    "name": "Obama",
    "gender": "M",
    "country": "JP",
    "id": "3"
  }
]
```

Obviously, I need to remove "element" (array name?)

How can I achieve this using JavaScript?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If the original object is in variable original:

```
original.element
```

would return what you want

Answer (score 1):

if your data is stored in `data` you can get it as

```
new_array = data.element
```

`new_array` will contain the desired array

Comment: It's not a "new_array". It's the same old array.

Comment: @torazaburo it was for explanation, and point was that it is being stored in new variable. why are you criticizing everything at every answer?

Answer (score 0):

I have created a [fiddler](https://jsfiddle.net/evrw66as/) for you.

```
var jsonString = '{"element":[{"name":"Donald","gender":"M","country":"US","id":"1"},{"name":"Hilary","gender":"F","country":"FR","id":"2"},{"name":"Obama","gender":"M","country":"JP","id":"3"}]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
var children = JSON.stringify(obj.element);
console.log(children);       //logs the required array as string


//you can use obj.element if you want to use array that's inside "element".
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your initial object is stored in a variable named: `data`.

As such, `data.elelment` will return your desired result.

The snippet below illustrates the above:

```js
  var data = {
  "element": [
    {
      "name": "Donald",
      "gender": "M",
      "country": "US",
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "name": "Hilary",
      "gender": "F",
      "country": "FR",
      "id": "2"
    },
    {
      "name": "Obama",
      "gender": "M",
      "country": "JP",
      "id": "3"
    }
  ]
}
console.log(JSON.stringify(data.element));
```